# Creating custom validation annotation using built-in annotations

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

In a system, I'm working in, the `username` must be either `email` or `cell number`.

I'm using [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) to validate the bean.

I want to create a custom annotation `@Username` such that it validate a bean property to be either `email` or a `cell number`.

Email can be validated with `@Email` and cell number with a regex using `@Pattern` but I couldn't figure out how to write a custom validator such that I can reuse above built-in annotations.

I referred to [Creating custom validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-customconstraints.html) section to create custom validator.

Basically my question is,

How can I use built-in validation annotations (`@Email` and `@Pattern`) to compose a new annotation `@Username` such that `@Username` validate a property to be either `email` or `cell number`?

```
// @Email or @Pattern("...") ???
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface Username {
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be Bean Validation compliant, you cannot. There is no concept of OR composition of constraints. However, if you are using Hibernate Validator and you are ok with provider specific features you can make use of boolean composition in Hibernate Validator - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-boolean-constraint-composition

```
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
@ConstraintComposition(OR)
@Email
@Pattern("...")
public @interface Username {
   /* ... */
}
```